# Not getting exact search filter result in Datatables

Tags: datatables

I am using `data-table 1.9`.I am not able to get the exact filter search result.
Like in data-table row i have word

```
"Hello Word, Hello Test"
```

when i type `"Hello W"` in search filter its not filtering the result.

```js
$('#tableSearch').on("change keyup", function () {
   oTable_myTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: That should defently work - see this example -> http://jsfiddle.net/H5f86/

Comment: Please type "Firefox 1." in table there is also:
Firefox 2.0
Firefox 3.0